# Как посмотреть sql-код выполняемой транзакции, зная transaction_id?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Также буду благодарен за совет, как посмотреть sql-код сессии, если известен SPID.

Ms Sql 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте динамические представления, например,

```
select session_id, text  from  sys.dm_exec_requests  mg 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(mg.sql_handle)  t
```

> Также буду благодарен за совет, как посмотреть sql-код сессии, если известен SPID.

Разве это не одно и то же?

Comment: Моя благодарность не знает границ. СПАСИБО!!!!

Comment: Моя благодарность будет безгранична в пределах разумного. (с)